# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1), Splitting string into two parts with split() didn't work

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string : `5kg`.
I need to make the numerical and the textual parts apart. So, in this case, it should produce two parts : `5` and `kg`.

For that I wrote a code:

```
grocery_uom = '5kg'
unit_weight, uom = grocery_uom.split('[a-zA-Z]+', 1)

print(unit_weight)
```

Getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-23a4dd3345a6> in <module>()
      1 grocery_uom = '5kg'
----> 2 unit_weight, uom = grocery_uom.split('[a-zA-Z]+', 1)
      3 #print(unit_weight)
      4 
      5 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
    print(uom)
```

**Edit:**
I wrote this:

```
unit_weight, uom  = re.split('[a-zA-Z]+', grocery_uom, 1) 
print(unit_weight)
print('-----')
print(uom)
```

Now I am getting this output:

```
5 
-----
```

How to store the 2nd part of the string to a var?

**Edit1:**
I wrote this which solved my purpose (Thanks to Peter Wood):

```
unit_weight = re.split('([a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)[0]
uom = re.split('([a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)[1]
```

Comment: Splitting using [**`str.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) doesn't use regular expressions, you just specify delimiters. You probably want [**`re.split`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split). e.g. `re.split('[a-zA-Z]+', grocery_uom, 1)`

Comment: @PeterWood : check edit plz.

Comment: If you want to include the matched splitting group you need to use `'([a-zA-Z]+)'`, however, this will produce `['5', 'kg', '']`, I'm not yet sure why. There are probably better ways than splitting, e.g. just matching the pattern instead.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote this which solved my purpose:
unit_weight = re.split('([a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)[0]
uom = re.split('([a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)[1]

Comment: @Debbie check answer below to include cases with numbers with commas (>=1,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex split rather than simple string split and the precise pattern you are looking for splitting is this,

```
(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Basically the point where is preceded by digit, hence this regex `(?<=\d)` and followed by alphabets, hence this regex `(?=[a-zA-Z]+)` and it can be seen in this demo with pink marker.

**[Check the pink marker from where the split will take place](https://regex101.com/r/PM25Ml/1)**

Also, here is your modified Python code,

```
import re

grocery_uom = '5kg'
unit_weight, uom = re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)

print('unit_weight: ', unit_weight, 'uom: ', uom)
```

Prints,

```
unit_weight:  5 uom:  kg
```

Also, if there can be optional space between the number and units, you can better use this regex which will optionally consume the space too during split,

```
(?<=\d)\s*(?=[a-zA-Z]+)
```

**[Demo allowing optional space](https://regex101.com/r/PM25Ml/2)**

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to split on the "kg", because that means it's not part of the actual data. Although looking at the docs, I see you can include them https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html But the split pattern is intended to be a separater.

Here's an example of just making a pattern for exactly what you want:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<weight>[0-9]+)\W*(?P<measure>[a-zA-Z]+)')

text = '5kg'
match = pattern.search(text)
print (match.groups())
weight, measure = match.groups()
print (weight, measure)
print ('the weight is', match.group('weight'))
print ('the unit is', match.group('measure'))
print (match.groupdict())
```

output

> ('5', 'kg')
>   5 kg
>   the weight is 5
>   the unit is kg
>   {'weight': '5', 'measure': 'kg'}

Comment: You aren't actually taking advantage of the `(?P...)` groups; you're just treating the result as a normal tuple. `re.compile(r'([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)')` will suffice in that case.

Comment: Since this is a pattern on the data, I was able to account for optional whitespace by just adding it to the pattern. Try it with " 5 kg "

Answer (score 1):

*updated to allow for bigger numbers, such as "1,000"
Try this.

```
import re
grocery_uom = '5kg'
split_str = re.split(r'([0-9,?]+)([a-zA-Z]+)', grocery_uom, 1)
unit_weight, uom = split_str[1:3]

## Output:  5 kg
```

Comment: This matches nonsense input as well, though, like `,10kg`. You'll want to verify that `unit_weight` is actually a valid number afterwards.

Comment: @chepner agreed but otherwise you could miss out on numbers > 999 with commas. somehow will need to add "do not match leading comma"? or is there a better standard protocol for such cases??

Comment: You're assuming the input *uses* commas. If it does, then of course the regular expression has to accommodate them. But you'll want to verify that the commas are used *correctly*, with something like `r'((?:[1-9]\d{0,2}))(?:,\d{3})*)`.

Comment: (You're also assuming the `,` is the thousand's separator, which isn't a universal convention, but dealing with that is beyond the scope of this question.)